# weird outDir typescript behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

My problem is really simple, but a bit annoying. I got a project written in Angular 2. I like keeping the build files on a separate folder so I set the 
outDir in typescript compiler options to "dist"

When I build my project on my windows machine i get the following structure

```
dist
 |--app
     |--components
```

When I build the same source on my mac I get the project folder as well

```
dist
 |--projectFolder
     |--app
         |--component
```

So I need everytime to change the

```
map:{
 app: 'path'
}
```

on my systemJS file

Anyone got any Ideas why is that happening?

here is the tsconfig.json as requested

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "app"
  }
}
```

EDIT:
I found what is causing it but still, I can't really explain it.
Because my project has some angular 2 external components (developed by me) when those npm components have an npm link the tsc creates the projectFolder when they are directly install from npm then the projectFolder is not created. It has nothing to do with being on a mac or windows. Still I cant understand why.

Comment: could that be because you are running typescript compiler in a different directory on windows relative to your mac computer?

Comment: no, not really cause the compilation is done through package.json. So i do npm start which executes tsc

Comment: can you share your tsconfig.json? maybe we can see something in it. :)

Comment: check which version of typescript your using, some would work out the `rootDir` by looking for the the most common folder to all the inputs.